# JavaScript, for each hover over change the text color

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have 4 `div` (colored box) and each `div` represent a different color.
When a user hovers over one of the colored boxes the text to display ("Hello world") should change to the color that is being hovered over.
I wrote the code for each color, but it seems worng because I'm copying the code many times for each color. How can I make this code shorter and more efficient?

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {

  const textToChange = document.getElementById('change_heading');

  const brownColor = document.querySelector('.brown');
  const greenColor = document.querySelector('.green');
  const blueColor = document.querySelector('.blue');

  brownColor.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    textToChange.classList.add('brown');
  });

  brownColor.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
    textToChange.classList.remove('brown');
  });

  greenColor.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    textToChange.classList.add('green');
  });

  greenColor.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
    textToChange.classList.remove('green');
  });

  blueColor.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
    textToChange.classList.add('blue');
  });

  blueColor.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
    textToChange.classList.remove('blue');
  });

});
```

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.brown {
  background-color: brown;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="change_heading">Hello World</h1>
SELECTED COLOR <span class="selected">None!</span>
<section>
  <div class="brown"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
  <div class="yellow"></div>
</section>
```

Comment: write a function that takes two arguments `function hover(element, colour)` - call it like `hover(blueColor, 'blue')` - that should give you a clue

Comment: `How can I make this code shorter and more efficient?` is pretty much a code review request not a specific coding issue. It would fit better at [Code Reviw Stack Exchange](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could shorten your code this way:

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function() {
  const textToChange = document.getElementById('change_heading');
  const corloredDivs = document.querySelectorAll('section div');
  
  corloredDivs.forEach(d=>{
      d.addEventListener('mouseover', function() {
          textToChange.classList.add(d.classList[0]);
      });
      d.addEventListener('mouseout', function() {
        textToChange.classList.remove(d.classList[0]);
      });
   });

});
```

```css
div {
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
}

.brown {
  background-color: brown;
}

.green {
  background-color: green;
}

.blue {
  background-color: blue;
}

.yellow {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<h1 id="change_heading">Hello World</h1>
SELECTED COLOR <span class="selected">None!</span>
<section>
  <div class="brown"></div>
  <div class="green"></div>
  <div class="blue"></div>
  <div class="yellow"></div>
</section>
```

Answer (score -1):

The above code is absolutely better. This is how I have shortened it.

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {

const textToChange=document.getElementById('change_heading');

  let allDivs = document.getElementsByClassName('a');

for (const div in allDivs) {
  let currentClassName = allDivs[div].className.split(" ")[1];
  allDivs[div].addEventListener('mouseover', function(){
    textToChange.classList.add(currentClassName);
});
    allDivs[div].addEventListener('mouseout', function(){
    textToChange.classList.remove(currentClassName);
});
}
});
```

```css
 div {
        width: 50px;
        height: 50px;
        display: inline-block;
    }
    .brown {
        background-color: brown;
    }

    .green {
        background-color: green;
    }

    .blue {
        background-color: blue;
    }
    .yellow {
        background-color: yellow;
    }
```

```html
<body>
<h1 id="change_heading">Hello World</h1>
SELECTED COLOR <span class="selected">None!</span>
<section>
    <div class="a brown"></div>
    <div class="a green"></div>
    <div class="a blue"></div>
    <div class="a yellow"></div>
</section>
<script src="script.js"></script>
```

Comment: Even though your code is working it also outputs an error.

Comment: Is this because I am using for in. I think just for loop will work here.